# Use a router for setting up developmental sub-network from primary business network

Tags: networking, ubuntu, router, switch, development

Scenario: Primary business network goes down due to an undetermined issue with firewall (Note: we're not the only business with this firewall having issues). This issue is addressed with a power cycle, which restores access to internet for some but not all devices. These devices without internet are being given IP configuration settings from a laptop running Ubuntu set to share IP addresses. The laptop is in this configuration for the purposes of developing with a Jetson Nano, and it's only when we set the laptop to not share IP addresses and we reset the primary network switch do we restore internet access to the remaining devices.

My question: Is purchasing another router sufficient to isolate the development laptop from the rest of the network for configuration settings while still maintaining access to the internet for this development laptop? Or is there a more complex network setup required to prevent my scenario from happening? The goal is to give the laptop as much freedom as possible for development purposes while minimizing or mitigating any local network mishaps stemming from the laptop.

Comment: What about a better business router?  A top grade business router (Cisco, Juniper, Sonic Wall) can handle several dozen people without going down.

Comment: Unfortunately, it was our Sonic Wall that went down in a circumstance where network traffic from the business was minimal. It happens, even the best tech can have non-ideal edge cases; we're leaving the RCA to the network admin folks.

Comment: Consider getting it serviced or replaced. I have use Sonic Wall and no issues.

Comment: Our network guys are already on it. According to them, it was an issue that affected other businesses in our area that use the same or same-family Sonic Wall. Until today we hadn't experienced any issues with ours. What I'm trying to address is this second issue with a development laptop attempting to provide IP configuration settings that flew under the radar until we had a network outage and several devices try to come up all at once. I might be wishing for pixie dust, but I would like to isolate this laptop to allow for some freedom in network development while still giving it internet.